# Plot lower triangle in a seaborn Pairgrid

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm a bit struggling with seaborn Pairgrid.

Let's say I have a Pairgrid like this:

[image]

As you can see, the upper triangle plots mirror the lower triangle ones.
I'd like to be able to plot only the lower triangle plots, but I found no easy way so far to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With seaborn >= 0.9.1:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(iris, corner=True)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also remove the histograms on the diagonal with `for ax in g.diag_axes: ax.set_visible(False)`

Comment: Also, with simple swapping of indices, `g.axes[i, j].set_visible(False)` plots upper triangle

Comment: How to show the y axis of the top figure?

Answer (score 17):

this is basically the same as the accepted answer, but uses the official methods from [`seaborn.PairGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="ticks")
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

def hide_current_axis(*args, **kwds):
    plt.gca().set_visible(False)

g = sns.pairplot(iris)
g.map_upper(hide_current_axis)
```

hiding the lower half is also easy:

```
g.map_lower(hide_current_axis)
```

or hiding the diagonal:

```
g.map_diag(hide_current_axis)
```

alternatively, just use the `PairGrid` directly for more control:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species', diag_sharey=False)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, alpha=0.3, edgecolor='none')
g.map_diag(sns.histplot, multiple="stack", element="step")
g.map_upper(hide_current_axis)
```

which gives:

[image: money shot]

[Since Seaborn 0.9.1](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-9-1-january-2020) there has been a `corner=True` setting, allowing the above to be changed to:

```py
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(
  iris, hue='species', corner=True, 
  plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.3, edgecolor='none'),
  diag_kind="hist",
  diag_kws=dict(multiple="stack", edgecolor='none'),
)
```