# How to show some selected rows with FacetGrid

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, facet-grid

I have a dataframe and with a column called "my_row". It has many values. I only want to see some of the data on FacetGrid that belong to specific values of "my_row" on the row. I tried to make a subset of my dataframe and visualize that, but still somehow seaborn "knows" that my original dataframe had more values in "my_row" column and shows empty plots for the rows that I dont want.
So using the following code still gives me a figure with 2 rows of data that I want and many empty plots after that.

```
X = df[(df['my_row']=='1') | (df['my_row']=='2')].copy()
g = sns.FacetGrid(X, row='my_row', col='column')
```

How can I tell python to just plot that 2 rows?

I get plots like this with many empty plots:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this. The code from the question seems to work fine. Here we have a dataframe with four different values in the `my_row` column. Then filtering out two of them creates a FacetGrid with only two rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"my_row" : np.random.choice(list("1234"), size=40),
                   "column" : np.random.choice(list("AB"), size=40),
                   "x" : np.random.rand(40),
                   "y" : np.random.rand(40)})

X = df[(df['my_row']=='1') | (df['my_row']=='2')].copy()

g = sns.FacetGrid(X, row='my_row', col='column')
g.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: YES! It must work like it is working for you. But I dont understand at all why it is not working for me and my data :/

Comment: That is true. I will see how I can provide that next week probably.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this problem-- the issue is that `my_row` is a categorical type. To solve, change this to a str.

i.e.

```
    X = df[(df['my_row']=='1') | (df['my_row']=='2')].copy()
    X['my_row']=X['my_row'].astype(str)
    g = sns.FacetGrid(X, row='my_row', col='column')
```

This should now work! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by this link:
[Plot lower triangle in a seaborn Pairgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087126/plot-lower-triangle-in-a-seaborn-pairgrid)

and changed my code to this:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='my_row', col='column')
for i in list(range(2,48)):
    for j in list(range(0,12)):
        g.axes[i,j].set_visible(False)
```

So I had to iterate over each plot individually at make it invisible. But I think there should be an easier way to do this. And  in the end I still don't understand how FacetGrid knows anything about the size of my original dataframe `df` when I use `X` and its input.

This is an answer that works, but I think there must be better solutions. One problem with my answer is that when I save the figure, I get a big white space in the saved plot (corresponding to the axes that I set their visibility to False) that I do not see in jupyter notebooks when I am running the code. If FacetGrid just plots the dataframe that I am giving it as the input (in this case `X`), there would have been no problem anymore. There should be a way to do that.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: This is an answer that works, but I think there must be better solutions. One problem with my answer is that when I save the figure, I get a big white space in the saved plot (corresponding to the axes that I set their visibility to False) that I do not see in jupyter notebooks when I am running the code.
If FacetGrid just plots the dataframe that I am giving it as the input (in this case ```X```), there would have been no problem anymore. There should be a way to do that.